# Extra space in formatting tips for HTML + Markdown

Tags: bug, markdown, editing-help, html-entities

There is an extra space in formatting tips for the text editor:

> [image: space after asterisk]

The text inserted as is produces the following:

> <strike>Markdown works * fine* in here.</strike>

But we're expecting *italic style* for "fine" word:

> <strike>Markdown works *fine* in here.</strike>

So the space after the first asterisk should be removed from the description.

Note: such formatting tips are visible only for [new question page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). If you're editing an existing post or answering the tips look different:

> [image: tips for answering and edit]

This looks a bit inconsistent.