# Unable to translate "markdown in HTML" part of formatting tips

Tags: bug, markdown, localization, editing-help

There's an untranslatable sentence in formatting tips while [asking a new question](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask):

> [image: no translatable markdown]

Similar block has [translation](https://ru.traducir.win/strings/850) for post edit editor:

> [image: edit post tips translated]

Could this sentence please be added for translation DB?

Comment: Last year bug related to this bug but still not fixed: [Extra space in formatting tips for HTML + Markdown](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/356563/339911).